# Neo4j startup timeout on Arch Linux

Tags: neo4j, java, archlinux

[This doesn't really feel like a StackOverflow question to me, but the Google Group explicitly redirected me here.]

I am attempting to run Neo4j on Arch Linux, with a spectacular lack of success. Running `bin/neo4j console` times out. I am using `neo4j-community-1.9.5`. All of this information is from running it for the first time immediately after untarring.

Output to the console:

> ```
> Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
> Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
> 2013-12-07 00:00:02.698+0000 DEBUG [API] You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
> 2013-12-07 00:00:03.225+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
> 16:00:03.687 [main] WARN  o.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase - You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
> org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@4d9ecb' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:515)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:146)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:112)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:262)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
>     at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:88)
>     at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
>     at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.start(CommunityDatabase.java:54)
>     at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:168)
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87)
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50)
> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@1394a8d' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:515)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:146)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.stop(XaDataSourceManager.java:149)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:511)
>     ... 10 more
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:72)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.stop(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:301)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:511)
>     ... 13 more
> Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>     at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
>     at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.writeInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:743)
>     at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:723)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.writeOut(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:159)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.force(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:172)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.releaseCurrentLogFile(XaLogicalLog.java:678)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.close(XaLogicalLog.java:703)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:68)
>     ... 15 more
> org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@6d3bea' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:262)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
>     at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:88)
>     at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
>     at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.start(CommunityDatabase.java:54)
>     at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:168)
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87)
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50)
> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension@183608e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.start(KernelExtensions.java:113)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
>     ... 9 more
> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource@12d3734' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.bringToState(LifeSupport.java:404)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.add(LifeSupport.java:318)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.registerDataSource(XaDataSourceManager.java:196)
>     at org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension.start(LuceneKernelExtension.java:86)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
>     ... 12 more
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.(IndexProviderStore.java:85)
>     at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.newIndexStore(LuceneDataSource.java:299)
>     at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.start(LuceneDataSource.java:223)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
>     ... 17 more
> Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>     at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
>     at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position(FileChannelImpl.java:290)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.write(IndexProviderStore.java:169)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.create(IndexProviderStore.java:153)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.(IndexProviderStore.java:61)
>     ... 20 more
> 2013-12-07 00:02:15.217+0000 DEBUG [API] Failed to start database.
> 2013-12-07 00:02:15.221+0000 DEBUG [API] 
> org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Startup took longer than 120000ms, and was stopped. You can disable this behavior by setting 'org.neo4j.server.startup_timeout' to 0. Error code: 1
>     at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:204) ~[neo4j-server-1.9.5.jar:1.9.5]
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87) [neo4j-server-1.9.5.jar:1.9.5]
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) [neo4j-server-1.9.5.jar:1.9.5]
> 2013-12-07 00:02:15.225+0000 DEBUG [API] Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
> Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
> Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
> 2013-12-07 00:00:02.698+0000 DEBUG [API] You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
> 2013-12-07 00:00:03.225+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
> 16:00:03.687 [main] WARN  o.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase - You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
> org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@4d9ecb' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:515)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:146)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:112)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:262)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
>     at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:88)
>     at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
>     at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.start(CommunityDatabase.java:54)
>     at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:168)
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87)
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50)
> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@1394a8d' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:515)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:146)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.stop(XaDataSourceManager.java:149)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:511)
>     ... 10 more
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:72)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.stop(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:301)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:511)
>     ... 13 more
> Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>     at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
>     at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.writeInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:743)
>     at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:723)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.writeOut(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:159)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.force(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:172)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.releaseCurrentLogFile(XaLogicalLog.java:678)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.close(XaLogicalLog.java:703)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:68)
>     ... 15 more
> org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@6d3bea' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:262)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
>     at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:88)
>     at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
>     at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.start(CommunityDatabase.java:54)
>     at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:168)
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87)
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50)
> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension@183608e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.start(KernelExtensions.java:113)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
>     ... 9 more
> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource@12d3734' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.bringToState(LifeSupport.java:404)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.add(LifeSupport.java:318)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.registerDataSource(XaDataSourceManager.java:196)
>     at org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension.start(LuceneKernelExtension.java:86)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
>     ... 12 more
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.(IndexProviderStore.java:85)
>     at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.newIndexStore(LuceneDataSource.java:299)
>     at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.start(LuceneDataSource.java:223)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
>     ... 17 more
> Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>     at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
>     at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position(FileChannelImpl.java:290)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.write(IndexProviderStore.java:169)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.create(IndexProviderStore.java:153)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.(IndexProviderStore.java:61)
>     ... 20 more
> 2013-12-07 00:02:15.217+0000 DEBUG [API] Failed to start database.
> 2013-12-07 00:02:15.221+0000 DEBUG [API] 
> org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Startup took longer than 120000ms, and was stopped. You can disable this behavior by setting 'org.neo4j.server.startup_timeout' to 0. Error code: 1
>     at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:204) ~[neo4j-server-1.9.5.jar:1.9.5]
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87) [neo4j-server-1.9.5.jar:1.9.5]
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) [neo4j-server-1.9.5.jar:1.9.5]
> 2013-12-07 00:02:15.225+0000 DEBUG [API] Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
> ```

Contents of the log file:

> ```
> Dec 06, 2013 4:00:01 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
> WARNING: You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
> Dec 06, 2013 4:00:03 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
> INFO: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
> Dec 06, 2013 4:02:15 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
> SEVERE: Failed to start database.
> Dec 06, 2013 4:02:15 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
> SEVERE: 
> org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Startup took longer than 120000ms, and was stopped. You can disable this behavior by setting 'org.neo4j.server.startup_timeout' to 0. Error code: 1
>     at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:204)
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87)
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50)
>
> Dec 06, 2013 4:02:15 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
> SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
> ```

Java version information:

> ```
> java version "1.7.0_45"
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.3) (ArchLinux build 7.u45_2.4.3-1-i686)
> OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
> ```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Or where I could dig for more information? Or what I could do instead that might work?

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j is currently only supported on Oracle JDK, you're running on OpenJDK.

Also make sure your settings for number of files is correct, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-linux-notes.html#_setting_the_number_of_open_files.

Check as well if you got enough permissions for Neo4j to write to the data/graph.db folder.

Comment: Open files is set correctly to 40k, write permissions are granted. I will try changing the JDK.

Comment: Reread your description again. Try to run `bin/neo4j start` instead of `console`, maybe that helps.

Comment: `bin/neo4j start` also times out.

Comment: Retried with Oracle JDK 7. Behavior is identical to that with OpenJDK.

Comment: (Excepting, of course, that it no longer complains about the JDK being unsupported. But the timeout/error is unchanged.)

Comment: that sounds weird. If I'll find some time next week, I'll try to setup a Arch docker.io container to verify/falsify the behaviour you've observed - but no guarantees on this.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted to version 1.8.3, the second to latest stable. That version works fine and is sufficient to my purpose. Problem undiagnosed, but resolved enough.